# what is the difference between var myVar = ""; and var myVar;?

Tags: javascript, variables

In coding websites and other examples both are used in different exapmles. how are these correctly used and how they affect the javascript code?

`var raj;` and `var raj = ""`;

Comment: first: `raj === undefined` ,second  : `raj === ''`

Comment: When coding in a strict (`use strict`) environment, you cannot 'use' variables you haven't declared. You'll be forced to declare them earlier. If you're not sure what you're going to do with a variable, you can simply define it as `var raj` so you can use them later on.

Comment: thanks a lot for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

```
var raj;
```

raj is here undefined.

```
var raj = '';
```

raj is a string.

```js
 // undefined
var raj;
console.log(typeof raj);

// string
var raj = ''; 
console.log(typeof raj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myVar =''
  //undefined
var otherVar
  //undefined
typeof myVar
  //"string"
typeof otherVar
  //"undefined"
```